# Angular one-way binding in component setting value in parent, why?

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-components

I have a simple angular 1.5 component for a text field:

```
angular.module('myapp')
   .component('textComponent', {
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.textfield.value" value="{{$ctrl.textfield.value}}">',
      bindings: {
        textfield: '<'
      }
    });
```

And I am using that component in a directive, in this html

```
<text-component textfield="form.textfield"></text-component>
```

When I enter a value in that textfield and save my form, it works.  Sounds great right but why it is working?  I thought components get their own scope by default and I thought that the '<' is a one way binding, preventing changes in a child from propagating back into the parent.

Looking at angular docs I see:

> one-way binding does not copy the value from the parent to the isolate
>   scope, it simply sets the same value. That means if your bound value
>   is an object, changes to its properties in the isolated scope will be
>   reflected in the parent scope (because both reference the same
>   object).

Which now makes since, I am passing an object to the child as reference, as such properties in that object that are updated in the child will be reflected in the parent.

That leaves me with a couple questions.

**Should one-way bindings only be used with primitives?**

**Is there any gain in using a one-way binding with an object?**